# Is it possible to stub out or spy on the setState method in React when doing unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, sinon, enzyme

I have the following function in my component:

```
method(args) {
 fetch(args)
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      element: response
      error: false
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.setState({
      error: true
    });
  });
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test for it so I have mocked out the fetch call using fetch-mock with a custom response. I want to check if the state was updated when this method is called and it doesn't seem to be working.  I am using enzyme, expect, and sinon and have been unsuccessful in getting the spy to be called when I set component.setState = sinon.spy or stubbing it out. How can I check to see if setState was called with certain elements or is my approach to unit testing this wrong?

Comment: if you are using enzyme you can just fetch the component's state why do you need to stub the setState function? why is checking the state not enough? that being said yes you can mock it, 
`component.getInstance().setState = sinon.spy`. that should do it assuming `component = (shallow||render)(<Component>)`

Comment: The state is updated async so when I check it, it does not equal the correct value yet.  I tried the following:

   ` const setStateSpy = sinon.spy();`
    `const component = shallow(<Main {...props} />);`
    `main.instance().setState = setStateSpy;`
    `expect(setStateSpy.called).toBe(true);`

But this returns false.

Comment: you just told me the state is updated async if you cant check the state's value you won't be able to check that setState was called. the same reason applies. if is an async operation you need either to mock the async operation or to set a timeout depending on the nature of the async operation itself.

Comment: I did mock out the async operation, but the setState method is also an async operation per react. I can indeed get around it with a timeout but that seems like a hacky solution which is why I want to spy on the setState method.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you'll need to spy on/stub out `setState` in the prototype before instantiating your component. I was having a similar issue where simply spying on the `setState` method of an instance did not work. Based on https://medium.com/@tjhubert/react-js-testing-setstates-callback-907df1fe720d, here's an approach for sinon:

**Component.js**

```
...
method {
  this.setState({property:'value'})
}
...
```

**Component.test.js**

```
...
const setState = sinon.stub(Component.prototype, ‘setState’);
const component = shallow(<Component />);
component.instance().method();
expect(setState).to.be.calledOnce;
...
```

*Note: my use case was using jasmine, and eschews rendering to test behavior, so the solution I know works looks like:*

```
Component.prototype.setState = jasmine.createSpy();
const sut = new Component();
sut.method();
expect(sut.setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith({property:'value'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the method is called when the component mounts and the method has been stubbed, try this:

```
it('should update state with response', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Component />);

  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    expect(wrapper.state('error')).to.be.false;
  });
});
```

Returning a promise allows you to test async behaviour in a less hacky way than using a callback in a setTimeout.

I use sinon for stubs, so I'd have something like this in the test:

```
sinon.stub(window, 'fetch').resolves(mockedResponse);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I didn't know you could return a Promise to a unit test and that assertions would work after that promise resolves. Made my life so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily mock/replace the `setState()` method of the component and await its next execution. Something like this might do the trick:

```
function onNextSetState(component) {
  const instance = component.instance()
  const originalSetState = instance.setState.bind(instance)
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    instance.setState = (state, callback) => {
      originalSetState(state, (...args) => {
        instance.setState = originalSetState
        resolve()
        if (callback) {
          callback(...args)
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}

it('should update state with response', async () => {
  const component = mount(<Component />)
  component.instance().method()   // we assume this runs .setState inside()
  await onNextSetState(component) // we wait for the next re-render

  // we can be sure the state is what we want it to be:
  expect(component.state('error')).toBe(false)
})
```

Note that if you would like to await more than once, it might be easier/better to use something like an Observable instead of a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stub setState with the following:

```
let setStateStub = sinon.stub(prototype, 'setState')
```

You'll also want to restore() the original once you done with the stub. 
You can do this by adding the following after the stub:

```
setStateStub.restore()
```

:)